# Extension of Discrete Valuation Rings: Part II

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $(R, m_R, \kappa_R) $ a discrete valuation ring (DVR) with quotient field $K$, and $K \subset L$ a finite field extension. Let $ B$ be the integral closure of $R$ in $L$, (which in general is not a DVR), let denote by $\frak{P}_1, \frak{P}_2, ..., \frak{P}_m$ it's maximal primes lying over $m_R$. Then we obtain ramification decomposition $m_R \cdot B=  \frak{P}$$_1^{e_1} \cdot  \frak{P}$$_2^{e_2}  \cdot ... \cdot  \frak{P}$$_m^{e_m} $ and let $f_i:= [B/\frak{P}_i$$ : \kappa_R]$.

I'm looking firstly for a constellation $(R,B;K,L)$ satisfying following properties:

1. $L$ is generated by a single element $L=K(\alpha)$.
2. satisfies proper inequality $[L:K] >\sum e_if_i$.

Note that in order to satisfy 2. $L/K$ should neccessarily be not separable.

*A (pathological) variant:* Does there exist an extension $R \subset B$ produced as above such that moreover $B=(B, m_B, \kappa_B)$ is even also a DVR, $\kappa_R=\kappa_B$ and $e_{B/R}=1$, but $R \neq B$?

Comment: Serre hints at situations where this is possible, in *Local Fields*, I.4, and at what happens. Mostly you need $R$ to be non-excellent, so this is going to be hideous.

Comment: @Aphelli: That's interesting. Just from intuitive picture to develop better intuition how strange such rings could become, "excellent" rings carry on intuitive level three characteristic features: **(1)** beeing Grothendieck ring: movally that the completion behaves like coordinate ring ring of manifold/ regular scheme, **(2)** J-2: I haven't at all good intuition for it , do you have one? and **(3)** universal catenary: that's essentially that the inclusion towers of prime ideals behave like in Noetherian (esp fin generated) $k$-algebras, eg those appear as quotients of polynomial rings

Comment: So I'm wondering if to produce such ring extensions we really need to exploit the lack of all these three features simultaneously, or or does the pathology of such ring extensions I'm trying to construct lie on the lack of exactly one of these three features characterizing the excellent rings?

Comment: @Aphelli: So the openness of the regular locus. Do you know a "key example" how one should think of/ imagine/ "keep in mind" when pondering about rings which carry this distinguished property? In contrast, is there a rather "simple" counterexample, say in realm of $k$- algebras of fin type? Necessarily, $k$ should have positive characteristic

Comment: Ok, I think Stacks, Example 09E1 satisfies your conditions.

Comment: @Aphelli: Thank you. Could you shortly repeat, why in my assumptions the *universal* catenary (3) is already fullfilled? You deleted the comment where you elaborated it and I missed to reflect it fast enough :)

Comment: So I was mistaken, it’s the G-ring thing that matters. DVRs are universally catenary so that property doesn’t play a role.

Comment: @Aphelli: I see. But just from point of curiosity even though this not directly takes relevant part in the construction I'm looking for. So far I remenber correctly you made a short comment on (3) in context of constellation above, I cannot remember any more. Something that the ring extension I'm cosidering is automatically universally catenary...As you said, this is seemingly not immediately relevant for the problem itself, but does it neverless still hold "as logical statement", or was it just wrong?

Comment: Alright I see ( was still typing when you extended  your  last comment which answers my concern about univ catenary for dvrs), thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am summarizing what I’ve written in the comments.

By the discussion in I.4 of Serre’s *Local fields*, the formula holds whenever $B$ is finite over $R$, which happens when the extension is separable or $R$ is complete.

In fact, by Stacks Lemma 03GH, the formula will hold when $R$ is Nagata, ie (Stacks Lemma 0BJ0) when its geometric fibres are reduced. This is automatic when $R$ is a $G$-ring (eg excellent), which occurs for most reasonable rings.

To give an explicit counterexample, we follow Stacks Example 09E1.

Let $L$ be a field of characteristic $p$ and $K$ be a subfield containing $L^p$ such that $L/K$ is infinite. Let $A$ be the reunion of the $M[[x]]$ for all finite $K \subset M \subset L$. Then $A$ is a DVR with residue field $L$ and uniformizer $x$, properly contained in $L[[x]]$.

Let $f \in L[[x]] \backslash A$ (so $f^p \in A$). By Stacks Example 09E1, the integral closure $B$ of $A[f]$ is not finite over $A[f]$ hence not finite over $A$. However, it is still integral over $A$ and hence Dedekind (see Serre’s comments).

We obviously have an inclusion $A \subset B \subset L[[x]]$ with $A \subset L[[x]]$ local integral. Since $A,B,L[[x]]$ are Dedekind, the maps $A \rightarrow B$, $A \rightarrow L[[x]]$, $B \rightarrow L[[x]]$ are thus universally injective. It follows that $xB$ is prime and that $m=e=1$. Clearly the extension of residue fields is trivial so we are done.